# RegEx: Split string by separator and then by another

Tags: c#, .net, regex

There is a problem with needed behavior.

Assume there is a

```
sourceString = @"name1$$value1^name2$$value2^name3$$value3";
```

maybe more long string...

I'd like to first split by `^` separator and then by another `$$` to create dictionary based on this name-value pairs.

This string is stored in file so may be too long, any split operations may take too much time.
I hope there is a regex with match by `^` and internal groupmatch by `$$`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This regex `(.*?)\$\$(.*?)(?:\^|$)` will match the name value pairs, and here is a [Rubular to prove it](http://rubular.com/r/UvOXIClo3X). And to use it you can use the following code:

```
var input = "name1$$value1^name2$$value2^name3$$value3";
var pattern = @"(.*?)\$\$(.*?)(?:\^|$)";
var hash = new Dictionary<string, string>();
var match = Regex.Match(input, pattern);

while (match.Success)
{
    hash.Add(match.Groups[1].Value, match.Groups[2].Value);
    match = match.NextMatch();
}
```

Comment: I assume it's @"(?<name>(.*?))\$\$(?<value>(.*?))(?:\^|$)

Comment: @Lonli-Lokli, yes that is correct. Did you take a look at the Rubular? The matched groups are on the right. Also, please see my edit for usage.

Comment: Yes, I've just modified your variant for the LINQPad. Thx for your version!

Answer (score 0):

Why not use:

```
sourceString.Split(new char[] {'^'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

Then you can do the same for $$

Comment: As I mentioned before, it's gonna be time-consuming operation.

Comment: Are u sure that a simple split is more time consuming than a regex?

Comment: Right now I'm doing check ^) But to check I was needed a correct regex first. Ps Anyway I'm sure...

Comment: Hmmm. Actually, split works 4th times better than compiled regex.