# split by separator inside pieces split by another separator

Tags: regex, split

This is an excerpt of an example `.gtf` file. I need to split each line by the `\t` separator and then split only the last element I obtained by `;`.

```
X   Ensembl Repeat  2419108 2419128 42  .   .   hid=trf; hstart=1; hend=21
X   Ensembl Repeat  2419108 2419410 2502    -   .   hid=AluSx; hstart=1; hend=303
X   Ensembl Repeat  2419108 2419128 0   .   .   hid=dust; hstart=2419108; hend=2419128
X   Ensembl Pred.trans. 2416676 2418760 450.19  -   2   genscan=GENSCAN00000019335
X   Ensembl Variation   2413425 2413425 .   +   .   
X   Ensembl Variation   2413805 2413805 .   +   .
```

I was almost able to split by `\t` (I have got problems with the end of the lines) using this regex `(?:21$)|(?:\t*(.*?[^\t]+))` ([try it here](https://regex101.com/r/LrttRq/2)). 
I also tried to split the last element with if else and negative lookaround but without results.

*How can I do it?*

Related question: [RegEx: Split string by separator and then by another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17065363/regex-split-string-by-separator-and-then-by-another)

Comment: Which language?

Comment: I am using Python regexes, but feel free to answer as you like

Comment: What is the expected output? Reason I ask is that some rows don't have `;`

Comment: I'm also confused as to what you mean by "I have got problems with the end of the lines".  Do you mean the input is malformed?

Comment: If you are struggling with writing one regex to rule erm... match them all instead of writing one regex to get the last part and then another (or even built-in function almost every language has - split) to split the last element? Why make your life hard?

Comment: @zzxyz in the example I gave the match continues beyond the newline, so my regex is wrong. Input is ok

Comment: @Asunez just for knowledge sake of regex

Answer (score 2):

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/LrttRq/5). The second regex cleans whitespace from that element [as seen here](https://regex101.com/r/LrttRq/6).

```
\t|;(?=[^\t;]*$)
\t|;[^\S\t]*(?=[^\t]*$)
```

Match either of the following:

- Option 1

  - `\t` Matches the tab character
- Option 2

  - `;` Match this literally
  - `[^\S\t]*` Matches any number of whitespace character except `\t`. This is what cleans up the whitespace in the second regex.
  - `(?=[^\t]*$)` Positive lookahead ensuring what follows matches the following

    - `[^\t]*` Matches any character except `\t` any number of times
    - `$` Assert position at the end of the line

I realize this is likely a file so you'd open the file and then run this over each line, but I just took the sample you put in your question and split the string using `splitlines()` to mimic that behaviour.

[See code in use here](https://tio.run/##hZBda4MwGIWv468Isgvdh@RDrVJklFF2V0aFMagduJnOgI2SvIUN9t9drJ0UxraEcM7Fw8Mh3QfUreJ9L/ddqwFr4TgVzrDruk9oqYzYvzRoLTpRAmIhTSlJxmQJChkK7K1llYHezXFtoNSQUduEqjJGnT8VISWIRYShm5Nk0Rzy9x8aTrjz7xQyLakOBibHCfseNMJntgctqgB0qUwwqOJ4Fg@ZzGKCwogENLXjGHoTyryWKrtfrvK7xYocD005j85cj6WWJchWDQYesmjKAF3Z9yuakGjKI2r/3nE6LRV4Gy0C0zUSPO0W8DnfPBd5AdtL7zaz1ZYL370WPt61GgssFa5GvJFKGM/f@n3/BQ)

```
import re

d = """X    Ensembl Repeat  2419108 2419128 42  .   .   hid=trf; hstart=1; hend=21
X   Ensembl Repeat  2419108 2419410 2502    -   .   hid=AluSx; hstart=1; hend=303
X   Ensembl Repeat  2419108 2419128 0   .   .   hid=dust; hstart=2419108; hend=2419128
X   Ensembl Pred.trans. 2416676 2418760 450.19  -   2   genscan=GENSCAN00000019335
X   Ensembl Variation   2413425 2413425 .   +   .   
X   Ensembl Variation   2413805 2413805 .   +   ."""

print([re.split(r"\t|;[^\S\t]*(?=[^\t]*$)",e) for e in d.splitlines()])
```

Result:

```
[
    ['X', 'Ensembl', 'Repeat', '2419108', '2419128', '42', '.', '.', 'hid=trf', 'hstart=1', 'hend=21'],
    ['X', 'Ensembl', 'Repeat', '2419108', '2419410', '2502', '-', '.', 'hid=AluSx', 'hstart=1', 'hend=303'],
    ['X', 'Ensembl', 'Repeat', '2419108', '2419128', '0', '.', '.', 'hid=dust', 'hstart=2419108', 'hend=2419128'],
    ['X', 'Ensembl', 'Pred.trans.', '2416676', '2418760', '450.19', '-', '2', 'genscan=GENSCAN00000019335'],
    ['X', 'Ensembl', 'Variation', '2413425', '2413425', '.', '+', '.', ''],
    ['X', 'Ensembl', 'Variation', '2413805', '2413805', '.', '+', '.']
]
```

Comment: Upvoted, because this is awesome.  But...`'hid=trf; hstart=1'`  Incorrect, no?  (I read it as split the entire the last element obtained through tab splitting).

Comment: @zzxyz thanks, fixed. I read it differently. Giving the question a second read with your comment makes it more clear. I initially understood it as the last `;` in the last element.

Answer (score 1):

OP commented that Python was being used, but other languages ok.  So...I'm not sure how much, if any, of this applies to Python, but I more or less agreed with the comment that trying to do this with a single regex is silly.  Like, here's the perl to do it more or less with 2 splits:

```
perl -F"\t" -lane 'for $i (0..$#F){if ($i!=$#F) {print "$F[$i]"} else {print for split(/;\s?/, $F[$i])}}' input
```

To break this down, `-F"\t"` splits on tabs into an `F` array.  Then I loop through it and split on semicolons for the last element.  And...this is okay as a one-liner, but barely.  Trying to do much more with the output of this would start to get ridiculous.

But then I saw @ctwheels answer (here's the Perl equivalent):

```
perl -F'/\t|;[^\S\t]*(?=[^\t]*$)/' -lane 'print for @F' input
```

This is *awesome*.  The input's already split up and everything is done before I even start.  The "program" (`print for @F`) is merely printing the results...Meaning if I had other work to do, I could easily do it.  And truthfully, I only had to stare at it for a couple minutes before it stopped hurting my brain.  Possibly easier to understand than the "code" answer and basically portable between any PCRE-type language.